# How to find out which kernel module supports particular hardware

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, hardware, documentation

One of my customer asked me question about providing them driver for RAID controller card in the server. It seems that server vendor only provides firmware for the controller but no driver. Also chipset vendor doesn't include any linux instructions. Therefore, it seems that support should be directly in kernel. But how to check that? Grep of kernel source revealed information about hardware model in one of the modules C code - so I've got module name. However that doesn't seem like an information I could provide to customer back.

Is there any official list in documentation that would list hardware versions supported by particular module? Or any better way of finding such information?

Comment: Maybe the answers at https://serverfault.com/questions/718654/can-i-detect-hardware-raid-infromation-from-inside-linux would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but that's the other way around of what I need to do. Without touching the server I want to be sure which module should be loaded.

Comment: Then this might be useful http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Hardware/sata.html
anyway I would recommend trying the drivers and verify they works before telling the customer which module is required

Comment: the best way i've found to get detailed info on linux support for specific hardware is to google "linux brand model" or "linux vendor:device" (where vendor and device are the PCI device's ID codes.  also works for USB devices).    This should tell you whether it's supported by linux, and by what driver.  and may also find howtos, documentation, and/or blog posts about using that particular device with linux (and most importantly posts complaining about how the device doesn't work properly in linux and/or how to fix that if possible).

Comment: Thanks for that, I know that google will get me the information, but what I want to achieve is to get official documentation or hardware compatibility list that can be provided for enterprise user. I don't feel like random (I don't want to offend anyone's work) blog is something close to official statement. Still thanks for suggestions.